# Reset all networking files

Tags: networking

I want to reset all my networking files to default. The files include /etc/hosts, /etc/network/interfaces, /etc/resolv.conf, and more. How can I do that without re installing?

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1     localhost
::1           localhost
```

**/etc/resolv.conf**

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

**/etc/network/interfaces**

```
##Local Loopback

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.24
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.1.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

**iptables -L**

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Ooh, not easy... I ended up reinstalling to get it all working again...

Comment: Could you copy them off the live CD?

Comment: How were they changed ? /etc/hosts you would have manually edited or changed by setting a hostname perhaps. The others are normally automatically generated by networkmanager and can be reset with networkmanager.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I messed with them manually. I need it to reset because my lo interface does not work.

Comment: Post the files you edited and we can likely fix it

Comment: Also any iptables rules you may have. `iptables -L` for a start.

Comment: @muru, Added iptables -L

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Added the files.

Answer (score 0):

1. `/etc/hosts` should remain as it is.
2. Delete `/etc/resolv.conf`, make it a symlink to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` and run `resolvconf -u`.
3. Delete the entry for `eth0` from `/etc/network/interfaces`.

It looks like you don't have any iptables rules to be worried about.